# Post-animation, view1's initial position "hides" view2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm doing a simple programmatic, Y-axis translation on two neighboring views using ObjectAnimator.

The area vacated by the first view seems to "hide" the content of the second translated view that moves into those bounds.

I've tried invalidate() to no avail. What else should I be doing?

Comment: Can you post the code you used and the layout of the activity/fragment?

Comment: Try requestLayout() instead